# How to increase coverage for record types with lenses?

Tags: haskell, code-coverage, haskell-lens

## Background

I am using record types with the [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens). I have written some unit tests with HUnit and HSpec.

However, the hpc coverage report shows that the field accessors were never executed.

Thus, contributing to the lower coverage for the record types.

## Example

```
data MetricValue =
  MetricValue { _average   :: Maybe Scientific
              , _count     :: Maybe Scientific
              , _maximum   :: Maybe Scientific
              , _minimum   :: Maybe Scientific
              , _timeStamp :: Text
              , _total     :: Maybe Scientific
              } deriving (Generic, Show)

makeLenses ''MetricValue
```

The `_average`, `_count`, `_maximum`, etc. fields were highlighted in yellow indicating that they were never executed.

## Questions

How can I improve the coverage?

How should I probably test the record types with lenses?

Comment: Just ignore the coverage warnings. It's a waste of your time to write tests for field accessors - it's not like they can ever go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`makeLenses` does not execute the `_average` etc field accessor functions, it merely uses them to construct the lenses.

If you write code that uses `aValue ^. average` then the `_average` function will be called by the lens.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks but the accessors are marked as ‘never executed’ even though the lenses were called in the tests.